# Image Slider in windows app

Tags: c#, winforms, image

I am working on a windows form application.

I want a image slider to be displayed at the bottom of my windows application, something like this:
[Image slide example](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=bb2c3831a82f075e&resid=BB2C3831A82F075E!218&id=BB2C3831A82F075E!218&sff=1)
Image paths would be grabbed from a DB.  Any idea how to implement this?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on what an "image slider" is?

Comment: No. Your question should start... i tied something(solution, you write your own code) without of luck. And now you'll get [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I have added a picture box. And changing its image each time a timer ticks.
but what I really want is like 
https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=bb2c3831a82f075e&resid=BB2C3831A82F075E!218&parid=BB2C3831A82F075E!114&authkey=!AJsyQABJr2PXQbM

Comment: Forms or WPF?  Please add a tag.  Should that "button" be "bottom"?

Comment: Forms and it is @ Bottom , Sorry [ that was typo]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you want a slider that shows only one picture at a time or more, but you can adapt the code if you need the latter.

```
private void showImage(string path)
{
    Image imgtemp = Image.FromFile(path);
    pictureBox1.Width = imgtemp.Width / 2;
    pictureBox1.Height = imgtemp.Height / 2;
    pictureBox1.Image = imgtemp;
}
```

If you want it to work only on an automated mode, use only one method:

```
private void prevImage()
{
    if(selected == 0)
    {
        selected = folderFile.Length - 1;
        showImage(folderFile[selected]); 
    }
    else
    {
        selected = selected - 1; showImage(folderFile[selected]);
    }
}

private void nextImage()
{
    if(selected == folderFile.Length - 1)
    {
        selected = 0; 
        showImage(folderFile[selected]);
    }
    else
    {
        selected = selected + 1; showImage(folderFile[selected]);
    }
}
```

Now the timer and the start slideshow button:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{ 
    nextImage();
}

private void Start_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if(timer1.Enabled == true)
    { 
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        Start.Text = "<< START Slide Show >>";
    }
    else
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        Start.Text = "<< STOP Slide Show >>";
    }
}
```

From [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23082/A-Simple-Image-Slide-Show). However, if you need something more than this you can read check [ImageSlider from devexpress](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsControlsImageSlidertopic).

Comment: Thanks for the comment . but i already have gone through this article.
I want something like this
https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=bb2c3831a82f075e&resid=BB2C3831A82F075E!218&parid=BB2C3831A82F075E!114&authkey=!AJsyQABJr2PXQbM

Comment: it can't be that hard to adapt that code. show 4 images, and when the next button is pressed shift all of them to the desired direction. 
If you want that selection, draw a box or something around the selected image.